# new empty asp.net core project not able to run (Error 502.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am starting out with web development and running into an issue I haven't run into outside of web development.

I am unable to run web apps on my computer. I am creating a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application, running the app before adding any code I get a 502.5 error, But this process runs fine on my laptop.

I also get this output for the ASP.NET core web server:

WebApplication3> The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\Repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\WebApplication3.dll'

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, or another IDE, and what version? How are you attempting to build and execute the application?

Comment: I am using Visual studio community edition 2017

Comment: Does the file referenced in the output above exist? If not, what else is in the directory?

Comment: the folder exists, but there is nothing inside of the folder

Comment: It appears your project has not yet been built. How are you trying to execute the application? If you run "dotnet build" at the command line when in the C:\Repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3 directory, do you now see the dll?

Comment: So far I have been using visual studio to build, il will check to see if with command line

Comment: building is failing.